# Diagnostics reports that the license file cant be written

Tags: imageresizer

Sorry if this is a repeat but I'm not seeing anything else relating to this. Running the diagnostics page, it reports that the license file could not be written to app_data due to lack of permissions. The app is running under windows auth with impersonation, and the logged in user definitely has write/modify permission on app_data (many other files are written in there by the user).

So what does this mean? It suggests to me that the file write is not using the impersonated credentials. If so, then what credentials is it using?

Thanks for your help.
Chris

Comment: The worker process/application pool identity, most likely.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, that's got it. Added write/modify for the app pool identity on app_data and cleared the error message. However, there appears to be no file actually written to the folder. Is that expected?

Comment: It may be writing to a temp folder instead.